# Google Scripts paste special values deletes cell contents

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having this issue with several different equations with several google sheets.  The equation works, but when I try to remove the formulas the cell becomes blank (there is a value if I leave the formula).  Code example:

```
var ssTable = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Table");

ssTable.getRange(13,3).activate();

ssTable.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=sumifs(\'OTD Data\'!K:K,\'OTD Data\'!O:O,\"ON-TIME\",\'OTD 
  Data\'!P:P,\"<>#N/A\")');
var range = ssTable.getRange(13,3);    
range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly: true});
```

I've tried several ways to write this and nothing seems to work.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- You want to put only the value by removing the formula.

If my understanding is correct, how about modifying as follows? In this modification, the retrieved value is put to the cell using `getValue()` and `setValue()`.

#### From:

```
range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly: true})
```

#### To:

```
// SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // This might be required.
range.setValue(range.getValue());
```

#### References:

- [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)
- [setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.